# How to deploy multiple websites in a single Nginx server | virtual host

Tags: nginx-config

i am trying to deploy multiple websites in a single Nginx server | Virtual Host and everything looks good nslookup wise

I tried the following step

1. Create Document Root Directories

You will make two individual document root folders for each domain.

`$ sudo mkdir /var/www/html/example1.com`

`$ sudo mkdir /var/www/html/example2.com`

The **requests made** to the first example domain are served from `/var/www/html/example1.com`.

The requests made, for **example2 site** will be served from `/var/www/html/example2.com`

#### 2. Create index.html files

For the next step, create **index.html files** for each of the domains. Starting with the example1 website, add the following command.

`$ sudo vi /var/www/html/example1.com/index.html`

but when i lookup the ip address the webserver says

## It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

```
<title>www.example1.com</title>
<h1>Welcome to www.example1.com Website</h1>
</html>
```

**Save and close** the file to save the changes.

Repeat the same steps, for `example2.com` website.

#### 3. Open NGINX Configuration file

Open the NGINX configuration file at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` You can do it using this command:

`$ sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

#### 4. Create Server Blocks

Create two server blocks for each domain.

You can modify the values for `server_name` and root. It lets you add **specific domain names**. Also, add the **document root locations** for each domain.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/html/example1.com;
   index index.html;
   server_name example1.com;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}

server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/html/example2.com;
   index index.html;
   server_name example2.com;
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

#### 5. Restart the NGINX Server

**Restart the NGINX server** to apply the changes. Use the following command:

```
$ sudo nginx -t 
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Check the web browser & type `example1.com` to see the index page. Test the same changes, for `example2.com` domain.

You have configured two virtual hosts on **one server using NGINX**.

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: It looks like this is a HOWTO or a guide, not a question?